# Microsoft Teams - Sideloaded Connector doesn't show up in list

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm trying to write a Connector for Microsoft Teams and I'm having a really hard time getting it set up. Here's what I've done:

1. [As per documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/sideload), I've created a zip archive with two images and a `manifest.json` that describes my app/Connector.
2. Within Teams, on my team's View Team > Bots, I've clicked "Sideload a bot or tab` and uploaded the archive. (By the way, this is horribly placed and horribly named)
3. My app shows up in the list under bots. (Again, not a good place considering I didn't create a bot or list one in the manifest)

Now, when I go to Connectors, I would expect to see mine listed at the bottom under "Sideloaded Connectors" but it's not there. Why not?

PS: The Connector Developer Dashboard allows me to download a predefined `manifest.json` with schema v0.4. This appears to be very out of date.

Answer (score 4):

Aha! I figured it out. Or rather, one of two steps that I tried did the trick (I'm not sure which one):

1. I enabled the Developer Preview.
2. I accessed the Teams page from a desktop client instead of web.

@Microsoft - As far as I know, none of the documentation mentions this. I only discovered it by fiddling with every setting I could find. Please make this more apparent.

Comment: Step #1 is definitely the issue if you use v1.0 of the manifest, and indeed is not completely documented.  It should be become an unnecessary extra step in the near future but currently v1.0 manifest support is not in the public version of Teams just yet.

Comment: @RichMoe-Microsoft: Is that related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102385/new-connector-works-for-outlook-but-not-microsoft-teams)? I tried moving back to v0.5 or v0.4 of the manifest, but those don't allow me to specify connectors without also having galleryTabs or bots.

Comment: I haven't tried to repro your other issue, but it is definitely the case that 3rd party Connectors as part of Microsoft Teams needs to use the v1.0 manifest, follow current packaging specs (zip file with manifest + icons), turn on Public Developer Preview, and sideload per current instructions.