# New Connector works for Outlook but not Microsoft Teams

Tags: office365, office365-apps, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm trying to build an Office 365 Connector exclusively for use on Microsoft Teams based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/connectors-dev-dashboard). It seems to work for Outlook groups, but not for Teams.

I've successfully created a Connector on the [Connectors Developer Dashboard](https://outlook.office.com/connectors/publish) and configured it to work on Teams (image below), but when I click the "Connect to Office 365" button on my site, it gives me an error "No valid mailbox Found". When I change the settings of the Connector in the dashboard to support Outlook (and also check the Inbox and Group boxes), I no longer receive this error and instead get to choose the connection, but my team is still not on the list. Clearly Teams isn't being considered for the connection.

These settings:

[image]

Produce this error:

[image]

Is there something special I need to do to configure my team for new Connectors?

Just a checklist of things I've tried:

1. Sideloading and developer preview are enabled for my team.
2. The Connector in the Dashboard was made with the same Microsoft account as the one on Teams.
3. I created an app with the connector defined in the `manifest.json` and sideloaded it into my team.
4. URL is `https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Connect?state={my-state}&app_id={connector-id-from-dashboard}&callback_url=http://localhost:3000/enable-teams`

Answer (score 2):

The "Connect to Office 365" button indeed does not work, as the user first has to add the connector to a team.  We've updated our documentation to call this out, along with other Teams-specific instructions.

Comment: True, I too had a situation, the button working without adding the connector to the teams but now its not working,